Scalar triple product of three vectors that are represented as the sum of three non coplanar vectors.
I know that the scalar triple product of three vectors can be calculated using a determinant as follows:
$$
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\vec{\alpha}_1 & \vec{\beta}_1 & \vec{\gamma}_1 \\ 
\vec{\alpha}_2 & \vec{\beta}_2 & \vec{\gamma}_2 \\ 
\vec{\alpha}_3 & \vec{\beta}_3 & \vec{\gamma}_3 
\end{array} 
\right|
$$
where,
$$
\vec{\alpha} = \alpha_1 \mathbf{i} + \alpha_2 \mathbf{j} + \alpha_3 \mathbf{k}
$$
$$
\vec{\beta} = \beta_1 \mathbf{i} + \beta_2 \mathbf{j} + \beta_3 \mathbf{k}
$$
$$
\vec{\gamma} = \gamma_1 \mathbf{i} + \gamma_2 \mathbf{j} + \gamma_3 \mathbf{k}
$$
But, here, and in most cases, we use standard $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$ vectors as their components to represent them. The special property of these standard vectors is that they are all mutually perpendicular to each other.
Hence, the cross product of $\mathbf{i}$ with $\mathbf{j}$ gives $\mathbf{k}$.
But what if instead of $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$, some other three non-co-planar vectors such as $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ are used to represent the vectors $\vec{\alpha}$, $\vec{\beta}$, and $\vec{\gamma}$?
I read it in an example, that in that case, the scalar triple product,
$$
[\vec{\alpha} \, \quad \vec{\beta} \, \quad \vec{\gamma}] = 
\left| 
\begin{array}{ccc} 
\vec{\alpha}_1 & \vec{\beta}_1 & \vec{\gamma}_1 \\ 
\vec{\alpha}_2 & \vec{\beta}_2 & \vec{\gamma}_2 \\ 
\vec{\alpha}_3 & \vec{\beta}_3 & \vec{\gamma}_3 
\end{array} 
\right|
[\vec{a} \, \quad \vec{b} \, \quad \vec{c}]
$$
where,
$$
\vec{\alpha} = \alpha_1 \vec{a} + \alpha_2 \vec{b} + \alpha_3 \vec{c}
$$
$$
\vec{\beta} = \beta_1 \vec{a} + \beta_2 \vec{b} + \beta_3 \vec{c}
$$
$$
\vec{\gamma} = \gamma_1 \vec{a} + \gamma_2 \vec{b} + \gamma_3 \vec{c}
$$
But how does this equal to the scalar triple product?
We don't know if the cross multiplication of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ vectors would even have something to do with $\vec{a}$.
My question is: How is this result derived, and when can we do this?

I think the question has typos.

It's pretty straightforward to derive this and it holds for any type of $\{\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b, \boldsymbol c\}$. Notice
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol\alpha\\
\boldsymbol\beta\\
\boldsymbol\gamma
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol a\\
\boldsymbol b\\
\boldsymbol c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Moreover,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol a\\
\boldsymbol b\\
\boldsymbol c
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 &c_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol i\\
\boldsymbol j\\
\boldsymbol k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol\alpha\\
\boldsymbol\beta\\
\boldsymbol\gamma
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 &c_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol i\\
\boldsymbol j\\
\boldsymbol k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you can set this multiplication of matrices equal to the matrix containing the coordinates of $\boldsymbol \alpha$, $\boldsymbol\beta$ and $\boldsymbol\gamma$ in the canonical basis,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1' & \alpha_2' &\alpha_3'\\
\beta_1' & \beta_2' &\beta_3'\\
\gamma_1' & \gamma_2' &\gamma_3'
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 &c_3
\end{pmatrix},$$
and finally, applying the determinant on both sides we end up with
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1' & \alpha_2' &\alpha_3'\\
\beta_1' & \beta_2' &\beta_3'\\
\gamma_1' & \gamma_2' &\gamma_3'
\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\det\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\
c_1 & c_2 &c_3
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$[\boldsymbol\alpha\ \boldsymbol\beta\ \boldsymbol\gamma]=\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{vmatrix}[\boldsymbol a\ \boldsymbol b\ \boldsymbol c]$$

$\mathbf{ALTERNATIVE\ PROOF:}$ Instead of using matrices we can use indexes and Einstein's notation. As such,
$$[\boldsymbol{\alpha\ \beta\ \gamma}]=\boldsymbol\alpha\cdot(\boldsymbol{\beta\times\gamma})=\alpha^i\boldsymbol v_i\cdot(\beta^j\boldsymbol v_j\times \gamma^k \boldsymbol v_k)$$
where $\boldsymbol v_1=\boldsymbol a$, $\boldsymbol v_2=\boldsymbol b$, and $\boldsymbol v_3=\boldsymbol c$. Each
$\boldsymbol v_i$ can be expressed as $\boldsymbol v_i=v^j_i \boldsymbol e_j$ where $\boldsymbol e_1=\boldsymbol i$, $\boldsymbol e_2=\boldsymbol j$ and $\boldsymbol e_3=\boldsymbol k$. Thus,
$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha^i\boldsymbol v_i\cdot(\beta^j\boldsymbol v_j\times \gamma^k \boldsymbol v_k)&=\alpha^iv_i^\mu\boldsymbol e_\mu\cdot(\beta^jv_j^\nu\boldsymbol e_\nu\times \gamma^kv_k ^\sigma\boldsymbol e_\sigma)\\
&=\alpha^iv_i^\mu\beta^jv_j^\nu\gamma^kv_k ^\sigma\boldsymbol e_\mu\cdot(\boldsymbol e_\nu\times \boldsymbol e_\sigma)\\
&=\alpha^iv_i^\mu\beta^jv_j^\nu\gamma^kv_k ^\sigma\boldsymbol e_\mu\cdot\varepsilon_{\ell\nu\sigma}\boldsymbol e_\ell\\
&=\alpha^iv_i^\mu\beta^jv_j^\nu\gamma^kv_k ^\sigma\varepsilon_{\ell\nu\sigma}\delta_{\mu\ell}\\
&=\alpha^iv_i^\mu\beta^jv_j^\nu\gamma^kv_k ^\sigma\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\sigma}\\
&=\alpha^i\beta^j\gamma^k\det(\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b,\boldsymbol c)\varepsilon_{ijk}\\
&=\det(\boldsymbol \alpha,\boldsymbol \beta,\boldsymbol \gamma)\det(\boldsymbol a,\boldsymbol b,\boldsymbol c)\\
&=\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 &\alpha_3\\
\beta_1 & \beta_2 &\beta_3\\
\gamma_1 & \gamma_2 &\gamma_3
\end{vmatrix}[\boldsymbol{a\ b\ c}]
\end{aligned}$$

Thanks, but quick follow up question: in the last step, you've written the determinant of (i, j, k). How can you take a determinant of a non square matrix?

Well, $[\boldsymbol{i\ j\ k}]=\boldsymbol i\cdot(\boldsymbol{j\times k})=\text{det}(1!!!1)$.

Okay, but I don't see how you arrive at scalar triple product directly from matrices. Can you be a little more clear, for both in the LHS, and the matrix with (i, j, and k). Thanks.

See now if your doubts are cleared out.

yes, thank you. I get it now.
